# ProgressBar button doesn't show while service call in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to show ProgressBar when service call made.
Product.xml

```
<ProgressBar Name="loading1" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="535" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,311,0,310"/>
```

Product.xml.cs

```
loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  //loading start
getAllProductDetails();   //contain service call and bind data in list
loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;  //loading finish
```

Loading should start before "`getAllProductDetails()`" call and it should finish once "`getAllProductDetails()`" finish.

if I have also used `await Task.Run(() => getAllProductDetails());` it keep execution of next line of "`await Task.Run(() => getAllProductDetails());`". It must wait until "`getAllProductDetails()`" call complete it's job.

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: What is the code of `getAllProductDetails()`?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev "private async void getAllProductDetails()". It contains service call which get data from server and bind list.

Comment: Assuming you didn't do anything wrong, you need to change the return value of `getAllProductDetails()` to `Task`.

Comment: @NanjiMange: You should avoid `async void`. More info in my [MSDN article on async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev I am facing another problem. I have added separate ticket for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613869/how-to-handle-event-raise-in-await-method-to-manage-progressbar-in-windows-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getAllProductDetails()` to return `Task` instead of `void`

```
private async Task getAllProductDetails()
{
    // Body
}
```

And then call like this

```
loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  //loading start
await getAllProductDetails();
loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;  //loading finish
```

If any async function returns `void` you can't wait for completion of execution.

Comment: Will it work if there is another call of  "async Task" inside getAllProductDetails()?

Comment: I am facing another issue. I have added in separate ticket. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613869/how-to-handle-event-raise-in-await-method-to-manage-progressbar-in-windows-store