# How to handle event raise in await method to manage ProgressBar in Windows store app?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

I want to show progressbar while method call. I have handle it as suggested in this ticket: [ProgressBar button doesn't show while service call in windows store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597526/progressbar-button-doesnt-show-while-service-call-in-windows-store-app?noredirect=1#comment60794051_36597526)

It doesn't wait for event which raise inside current event.
i.e

```
public async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    await initializeThePage();
    loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}

//following method doesn't wait for SelectionChanged event. It should wait
private async Task initializeThePage()
{
    //few service call here
    cmdStore.SelectedIndex = 1;     //this should wait until cmdStore_SelectionChanged complete its call
}

private async void cmdStore_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //few service call here
    loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    await getOrderlistAccordingToStore(storeID);            //get store details 
    loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public async Task getOrderlistAccordingToStore(int storeID)
{
    //calls of get orderlist according to selected store
}
```

when `cmdStore.SelectedIndex = 1;` calls, it calls `cmdStore_SelectionChanged` method. In this case `await initializeThePage();` should wait until `cmdStore_SelectionChanged` completed. But it doesn't wait for this event and it keep continue with next execution.

Can anybody please suggest me how to handle event which raise inside current await call?

Comment: After setting `cmdStore.SelectedIndex = 1;` it there anything inside `initializeThePage` that is depending on `SelectedIndex` ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer  No, there is nothing depend after `cmdStore.SelectedIndex` called.`cmdStore.SelectedIndex = 1;` call gets store data and display data on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmdStore_SelectionChanged` is binded to event handler and is `async void`. You can't directly wait for completion of execution of this method

To you can do some workaround to handle that. First of all introduce helper methods to show/hide loader.

```
int waitCounter = 0;
void ShowLoader()
{
    waitCounter += 1;
    if (waitCounter > 1) // Already loader is visible 
        return;

    loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
}

void HideLoader()
{
    waitCounter -= 1;

    if (waitCounter <= 0) // No more call to wait for 
       loading.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

After that modify your implementation to look like this

```
public async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    ShowLoader()
    await initializeThePage();
    HideLoader()
}

private async Task initializeThePage()
{
    //few service call here
    cmdStore.SelectedIndex = 1;
}

private async void cmdStore_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowLoader();
    //few service call here
    await getOrderlistAccordingToStore(storeID);            //get store details 
    HideLoader();
}

public async Task getOrderlistAccordingToStore(int storeID)
{
    //calls of get orderlist according to selected store
}
```

When page is first initialized loader will be visible and will disappear when both `cmdStore_SelectionChanged` and `initializeThePage` completes its execution.